# Conditional logic in Docusgin

Tags: numbers, logic, conditional-statements, docusignapi

I have a legal document where if the money being paid to the vendor is over $5000, then the senior vice president has to sign the document. I'm currently using a text field where the value being paid to the vendor would be entered and wanted to use conditional logic for the scenario: if the value in the text box is over $5000, then the vice president's signature will be required" but this doesn't seem possible since the conditional logic for text boxes is rather restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have logic for required tab or not, instead you can use conditional logic for show/hide of the tabs. In your case, you can use text and formula tab to show and hide the Signature tab. Formula will return 1 if value > $5000 and it will return 0 if value is <= 5000. Now conditional logic on Signature tab should be on formula, show Signature tab only when formula value is 1 else do not show Sign tab.